# Ionic 4 named ion-router-outlet content bug with lazy loaded Tabs layout

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic@rc(Ionic 4) with @ionic/lab@rc(Ionic Lab).
I've created a new project using tabs starter template. Everything ran fine up until I modified the project to lazy load home/about/contact modules.

The tabs are being shown but the rest of the page is just black screen when serve in ionic lab(white screen if I serve the app using ionic serve). The modules are being properly lazy loaded since module ctors are being called when first navigating to each tab and there are no errors in the console. Has anyone stumbled upon this issue? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[Screenshot taken from ionic lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVR95.jpg)

angular.json:

```
{
  "name": "tabstest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ionic serve",
    "build": "ionic build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@ionic/lab": "^1.0.0-rc.11",
    "@ionic/ng-toolkit": "1.0.0-rc.11",
    "@ionic/schematics-angular": "1.0.0-rc.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "rxjs": "6.2.1",
    "semver": "^5.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.7",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.7.0-rc.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.7.0-rc.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.7.0-rc.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.7.0-rc.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.5.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.10.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

AboutRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutPage } from './about.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AboutPage, outlet: 'about'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AboutRoutingModule { }
```

AboutPageModule:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AboutPage } from './about.page';
import { AboutRoutingModule } from './about-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AboutRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [AboutPage]
})
export class AboutPageModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('AboutPageModule loaded.');
  }
}
```

about.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>About</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>About us</ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="logo-ionic" slot="start"></ion-icon>
     About Ionic!
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

AboutPage:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['about.page.scss']
})
export class AboutPage {}
```

Home and Contact pages follow the same pattern, so I will be omitting them for brevity.

TabsPageRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        outlet: 'about',
        loadChildren: '../about/about.module#AboutPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        outlet: 'contact',
        loadChildren: '../contact/contact.module#ContactPageModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

TabsPageModule:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { TabsPageRoutingModule } from './tabs.router.module';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TabsPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('TabsPageModule loaded.');
  }
}
```

tabs.page.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="Home" icon="home" href="/tabs/(home:home)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="About" icon="information-circle" href="/tabs/(about:about)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="about"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Contact" icon="contacts" href="/tabs/(contact:contact)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="contact"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss']
})
export class TabsPage {}
```

AppRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('AppModule loaded.');
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14566) in ionic 4 and they blame it on Angular

Comment: Did you got it fixed? I have a similiar problem. I want to redirect to e.g. /auth/login and want to view the login inside the auth component to have a global logo set in auth that is also displayed in login and other routes under auth... I tried to set `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in auth.component.html but get a blank page.

Comment: I am also having this issue simply by using any named ion-router-outlet. Even if it is the only outlet. Seems like a pretty blocking bug... anyone get this fixed?